# How to call an async arrow function with await

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I define a function like this:

```
const getName = async () => await Promise.resolve('John');
```

When I try to call the getName function with async:

```
const name = await getName();
console.log(`Hi ${name}`);
```

It throws an error:

```
const name = await getName();
             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `async` function should return a Promise as opposed to waiting for it to resolve: `return Promise.resolve('John');`. Then your `await getName();` call will have a Promise to wait for to be resolved.

Comment: @JimB. async function always return promises even when the function body doesn't.

Comment: Right.  Ignore that.

Comment: If I remove the await, the error is still the same

Comment: It's telling you the error :`await is only valid in async function` I look like you are trying `const name = await getName();` outside of an sync function.

Comment: @MarkMeyer what if this is the code of an index.js file? It is not in a function, is the body of the main file.

Comment: @carlos, then you can't use `await`. You either need to wrap it in an async function or use `getName.then()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> const getName = async () => await Promise.resolve('John');
> ```

In the above, you have an async function (the arrow function) which uses `await` inside.

This is fine (albeit pointless as you could return the promise directly).

Here:

> ```
> const name = await getName();
> ```

You use `await` again, and while the function on the right-hand side does return a promise, the function it appears inside is not `async` so it is not valid.

---

Put it inside an async function and it will be fine:

```js
const getName = async() => await Promise.resolve('John');

const init = async() => {
  const name = await getName();
  console.log(`Hi ${name}`);
};

init();
```

As mentioned though, making `getName` `async` and `await`ing inside is just a needlessly complex set of nested promises and you could simplify:

```js
const getName = () => Promise.resolve('John');

const init = async() => {
  const name = await getName();
  console.log(`Hi ${name}`);
};

init();
```